# How to retrieve bought items information inside an order

Tags: php, magento

I want to send a weekly reminder email to customers who have bought something but not paid yet.

Using this script I can show an order:

```
<?php
//from http://www.exploremagento.com/magento/run-magento-code-outside-of-magento.php
require_once '../app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app('default'); 

$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
        ->setOrder('increment_id','DESC')
        ->setPageSize(1)
        ->setCurPage(1);
$LastOrderNr = $orders->getFirstItem()->getIncrementId() - 100000000;  


$LastOrderNr=494;  
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($LastOrderNr); //put a valid order entity_id there;
print_r($order->debug());  
echo "<br/>******************************<br/>"; 

?>
```

I can retrieve several useful info-blocks (i.e. customer's email address, total amount) but it won't show the items they have bought. How/where can I retrieve that kind of information?

Answer (score 3):

In Magento ordered products called 'order items'. You can get order items data like this:

`

```
// 1. get order. you can load it by order entity id (f.e. 494)
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
// or by order increment id (100000494)
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);

// 2. get order items collection
foreach ($order->getItemsCollection() as $item) {
    Zend_Debug::dump($item->getData());
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

it can be much easier to get the last Order , especialy needed for the success Site

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->getLastItem()->getEntityId());
```

Example: Last Order Costs

```
$grand_total = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->getLastItem()->getEntityId())->getGrandTotal();
```